# Black screen after login after update (Intel GPU)

Tags: grub2, 13.10, graphics, intel

First, please do not mark this as duplicate. I have spent two days going through this website trying different things suggested.

I have 13.10 and using a Dell Inspiron Mini 1018 that has the following graphics:

```
sangie@Sangie-Netbook:/tmp$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display:0 UNCLAIMED   
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0200000-f027ffff ioport:18d0(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0000000-f00fffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0280000-f02fffff
```

I have my drive encrypted, if that matters, and after I unlock it and the system starts to boot, I see a black screen but the backlight is on and adjustments to brightness doesn't help. Please note that I have auto-login enabled so login screens never come up. I've tried booting to older kernels and even tried 3.9 with no help. The only way I can boot is to use nomodeset or recovery mode, but then I'm stuck at 800 x 600 resolution with no way to change it.

My system has been working fine for months and I'm pretty sure I updated the base right before this happened. The full resolution is 1366 x 600 (I believe) so 800 x 600 makes everything stretched. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**Other things I've tried:**

- Using Intel's driver installer and running that and letting it install it's own drivers.. issue persisted.
- Running system update again to the point where there's no more updates available.
- Trying to boot to previous kernels in Grub
- sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following first to update your intel driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

This may also be down to certain chipsets needing KMS in order to run X and a desktop environment such as GNOME, KDE, Xfce, LXDE, etc. KMS is supported by Intel chipsets that use the i915 DRM driver.

1. Dont use nomodeset or modeset=0, as it throws off KMS and you wont
   be able to do anything.
2. `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and add in the i915 and
   intel_agp drivers, save, and rebuild by running `update-initramfs
   -u`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately, none of this worked. I tried doing the intel-driver update as you listed and rebooted with no modifiers and I got teh black screen. I then went into recover mode and edited the file to look like this:

'# raid1
# sd_mod
i915
intel_agp'
And then I tried sudo update-initramfs -u and rebooted and same thing :< Any further suggestions would be great.